# Google sheet script array not giving correct values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've been trying to figure this out but cant seem to get it to work.

```
function Manager() {
var units = new Array(5,9);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:P16");
var x = 0;
var y = 0;


//Initial Setup
/*for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i = i + 1) {
  units[i*2, 1] = 8+((i*2)-3);
  units[(i*2) + 1, 1] = 8+((i*2)-3)*5;

  units[i*2, 2] = 8+((i*2)-3)*(-1);
  units[(i*2) + 1, 2] = 8+((i*2)-3)*5;

  units[i*2, 3] = 8;
  units[(i*2) + 1, 3] = 8+((i*2)-3)*5;

  units[i*2, 4] = 8;
  units[(i*2) + 1, 4] = 8+((i*2)-3)*6;

  units[i*2, 5] = 8+((i*2)-3)*(2);
  units[(i*2) + 1, 5] = 8+((i*2)-3)*7;

  units[i*2, 6] = 8+((i*2)-3)*(4);
  units[(i*2) + 1, 6] = 8+((i*2)-3)*7;

  units[i*2, 7] = 8+((i*2)-3)*(-4);
  units[(i*2) + 1, 7] = 8+((i*2)-3)*7;

  units[i*2, 8] = 8+((i*2)-3)*(-2);
  units[(i*2) + 1, 8] = 8+((i*2)-3)*7;

  units[i*2, 9] = 8;
  units[(i*2) + 1, 9] = 8+((i*2)-3)*7;
}

for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i = i + 1) {
  units[1,i];
  x = units[3,i];
  y = units[2,i];
  var cell = range.getCell(x,y);    
}
```

The result should be numbers 1 through 9 placed in somewhat organized pattern and mirrored at the 9 row mark. As an example, units[3,1] should be 3 and units [2,1] should be 7 but the result it gives me is 14 and 14. The total result is showing up 3 in N14, 4 in O15 and 9 in P16. I tried some debugging on the last "for" loop and the first 2 times 1 and 2 are also placed in N14 and being overwritten and everything from 5 to 9 placed in P16 being overwritten as well. Any thoughts on why the last for loop isn't actually giving the correct coordinates

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you've tried to create a 5x9 two-dimensional array, but the way you've attempted it is not valid in Javascript (which Google Apps Script is based on). Take a look at [How can I create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript).

Throughout your code, arrays are being indexed improperly. The indices should be separate, such as `units[3][1]`. When you provide a list, e.g. `[3,1]`, the last item is used as an index. That's why you saw `14` repeated. Additionally, you should remember that arrays are indexed starting from 0.

Changes like this will make your code manipulate a two-dimensional array:

```
...
//Initial Setup
var units = new Array();
for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i = i + 1) {
  units[i*2] = new Array();
  units[(i*2) + 1] = new Array();

  units[i*2][1] = 8+((i*2)-3);
  units[(i*2) + 1][1] = 8+((i*2)-3)*5;
  ...
```

And here's how `units` appears in the debugger after the initial setup, with the gaps apparent:

[image: Screenshot]